# Signature of a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

This may be a really dumb question, but here goes: is there any algorithm to compute the signature of a quadratic form (or a symmetric matrix, if you prefer)  more efficient (asymptotically or otherwise)  than actually computing the eigenvalues?

Comment: count sign changes in the determinants of the principal minors?  (This fails if one of them vanishes, but you can first compute the rank, then do a random coordinate change so you don't get any zeros before that.)

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Yes, true enough, but I am not sure if this is more efficient than computing the eigenvalues (in fact, I am pretty sure it is not, though I have been wrong before :))

Comment: I don't know.  Might depend on whether your matrix has floating-point or exact entries.  You might also consider Dodgson condensation, which is inefficient for a single determinant but possibly competitive for this question because it  gives you all contiguous minors along the way.

Comment: If the entries are floating-point, determinants are faster, provided that you compute them all at the same time with a $LU$ factorization (or better $LDL^T$, as suggested in ShakeBaby's answer) instead of one by one. In fact, forget about the determinants, just considering the signs of the diagonal entries in the factorization is enough.

Comment: Note that if the entries are floating-point, in addition to speed another issue is stability. The eigendecomposition (on a symmetric matrix) is probably going to be more stable in cases where you have "almost zero" entries.

Comment: Would you tell us what kind of quadratic forms you're working with? Are they real quadratic forms? What kind of specificity can you offer in terms of the problem you're hoping to solve?

Comment: @Justin I am interested in both the integer/rational case, and the "real" case. The latter comes in Morse-theoretic applications, the former in algebraic.

Comment: You can also do Gram-Schmidt on the indefinite inner product $<x,y> = x^t A y$. It finds a basis in which the inner product looks like a diagonal matrix with only $1,0,-1$ entries.

Answer (score 10):

Gauss reduction gives you the answer. It writes, quite fast, the quadratic form $q$ as a sum
$$\sum_ja_j\ell_j(x)^2$$
where the $\ell_j$'s are independent linear forms. The number of squares gives you the rank of $q$. The signs of the coefficients $a_j$ gives you the signature. I teach that in my undergraduate course in Algebra.

Remark that you cannot calculate the eigenvalues, at least in close form, because this is computing the roots of quite a general polynomial, and this is impossible in dimension $\ge5$.

Comment: Denis, could you please comment on my answer? Your method is what I know from books on integral quadratic forms, and I associate it with the name Hermite. Really just repeated completing the square(s) until all terms are exhausted, and not difficult. Then in 2015, on MSE, I came across the method in my answer, and started asking about it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr  My feeling is that they are really the same method, minor difference in finding either $P$ or $P^{-1}$ first in $P^T AP=D$

Comment: @Will. There is one difficulty, in that you can at some point have to reduce a quadratic form with no square at all. But then the form represents zero and you just look for a hyperbolic plane. I don't know the terminology Hermite (though he was a French mathematician). Perhaps the method has different names in different countries.

Comment: Denis, I think you are right. I am looking at my quadratic forms books, it seems Hermite reduction is far more specific thing. I saw your sum as part of that and incorrectly put his name on this general method.

Answer (score 8):

Thursday morning. Noam has suggested that this is equivalent to performing Gram-Schmidt **without normalization**. That would explain why I could not find any explicit point where anyone wrote "Here is a way to reverse Hermite's type of method." I'm going to try some 2 by 2 and 3 by 3 examples, see if I understand.

Here are explicit example(s) as links, in this first one the form is indefinite;

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427946/orthogonal-basis-for-this-indefinite-symmetric-bilinear-form

Igor, there is an easy algorithm that creates $P^T A P = D$ with $D$ diagonal, $\det P = 1$ and the elements of $P$ in the same field as that needed for $A.$

I can describe the way I do it. Let $A_0 = A,$ then $A_{j+1} = P_j^T A_j P_j,$ where $P_j$ is one of three types:

(I) the identity matrix, except for the value $t$ at position $i,j$ in the upper triangle

(II) the identity matrix, except $p_{ii} = 0,$ $p_{jj} = 0,$ $p_{ij} = 1,$ $p_{ji} = -1,$

(III) the identity matrix, except for the fixed value $1$ at a position in the *lower* triangle.

Oh, after doing several of these, I realized that a bunch of type (I) matrices with the extra off diagonal elements *in the same row* can be combined into one matrix, as such matrices commute with each other.

I had never seen it before, I asked about it at  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

In the most favorable cases, $P$ is also upper triangular. Not guaranteed.

[image]

Comment: Very cool! This is clearly superior over integer or rationals, a little harder to tell with floating point!

Comment: Is this basically Gram-Schmidt?  (Gram-Schmidt does find an equivalent quadratic form that's diagonal.)

Comment: @Noam I don't think so. We don't ever find out the eigenvalues this way. I think it is the same as Denis Serre's answer, which he calls Gauss reduction. That way, you gradually produce $D$ and the rows of some $Q$ with $Q^T DQ = A.$  This method, we gradually produce $P$ and get $P^T AP = D.$ So, the real difference is just $P = Q^{-1},$ unless different choices led to different diagonal $D$

Comment: Gram-Schmidt doesn't find eigenvalues either.

Comment: @Noam, right. I asked Denis for commentary. Maybe I should have said that, starting with a symmetric matrix of integers, this method or Denis's method never requires square roots, all numbers used in all the matrices are rational.

Comment: G-S doesn't require square roots either unless you insist that your basis be ortho*normal*, not just orthogonal.

Answer (score 5):

There's a large literature on "inertia revealing factorizations" for real or complex matrices. Usually one uses MA57 of the HSL implementation to compute the signature, which does an sparse $LDL^T$ factorization: http://www.hsl.rl.ac.uk/catalogue/ma57.html