# Is there a fast way to check if a matrix has any small eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, computation

I have hundreds of millions of symmetric 0/1-matrices of moderate size (say 20x20 to 30x30) which (obviously) have real eigenvalues.

I wish to extract from this list the tiny number of matrices that have **no small eigenvalues**, where I am calling an eigenvalue $\lambda$ *small* if it satisfies $|\lambda| < 1$.

Obviously I can do this by computing the characteristic polynomial of every matrix and proceeding from there. However I'd rather not calculate hundreds of millions of characteristic polynomials if I can avoid it.

So I am looking for techniques, heuristics etc that can be used to quickly test a matrix for the presence of a small eigenvalue so that I can immediately eliminate the matrix.

For example, if a matrix has determinant $0$ then it definitely has a small eigenvalue (namely $0$) and it can be eliminated immediately. Quick and dirty experiments with SageMath show that for a random sample of my matrices, the determinants can be calculated in about $6$% of the time required to compute the characteristic polynomials, and that about  $15$% of the incoming matrices have determinant $0$. Therefore I gain a little bit by first computing determinants and throwing away those matrices with determinant $0$.

It seems though that this property is somewhat special because only a minuscule fraction of my hundreds of millions have no small eigenvalues. However I have searched fairly hard and have only found a few tangentially-related references to matrices with this property, though a couple more about matrices with no eigenvalues of modulus **larger** than one.

***Question*** Are there are any other, perhaps more sophisticated, heuristics that can detect the presence of a small eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix?

Comment: You could use the [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number), computed as the ratio of the largest diagonal element and the smallest diagonal element.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Since the matrices are all 0/1-matrices, the condition number never tells me much.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni My current slow method (via characteristic polynomials) uses exact arithmetic only and does not compute any eigenvalues, but I would experiment with a heuristic involving floating point arithmetic if necessary.

Comment: @GordonRoyle How do you test if a polynomial has no roots inside the unit disc without computing the roots? Schur/Hurwitz stability criteria?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni They are symmetric matrices, so the unit disc is the unit interval so with a bit of pre-processing to eliminate repeated roots and roots at $\pm 1$ Sturm sequences can be used.

Comment: If $|A|\ne 0$ and either $|A+I|$ or $|A-I|$ has different sign from $|A|$, then there is a small eigenvalue.

Comment: Compared to the time for computing, say, the determinant, how long would it take to compute the matrix inverse?  If that were available cheaply you could, for instance, use the inverse power method.

Comment: The off-the-shelf eigenvalue computations that MATLAB uses can solve this problem (i.e., computing the minimal eigenvalue to, say, 8 decimal places) for 100 million $30 \times 30$ symmetric $\{0,1\}$ matrices in about 2 hours. If you want an exact answer you will need to use the characteristic polynomial when there is an eigenvalue really close to $1$, but can you use these numerical methods to rule out all matrices with an eigenvalue below, say, $0.999$?

Comment: see  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268334/signature-of-a-quadratic-form  That is, I think the command qfgaussred()  is what you want if you are working in pari-gp

Comment: Also, this is called Gauss reduction in France   although    often called Lagrange reduction  as in Gantmacher's books, pages 299-300 in volume one. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9duction_de_Gauss#

Comment: So, isn't the whole problem equivalent to deciding whether the matrix $A^2-I$ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: I have (undebugged) code about 100 times faster than Nathaniel reports for Matlab.

Comment: Got a reply from Pari-gp.  Both the commands qfgaussred()  and qfsign() run on rational numbers when given a square symmetric integer matrix. So, as in the idea of @BrendanMcKay,   run qfsign()  on $A, A+I, A-I,$  and compare

Comment: In case you're looking for ideas besides the ones provided in the answers below, you could consider also posting your question on Computational Science SE: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How much faster do you need? I just did a quick test with numpy on a M2 macbook, calculating the eigenvalues of a 20x20 0/1 symmetric matrix and checking the minimum absolute value (`np.min(np.abs(np.linalg.eigh(A)[0]))` ) took 90us, and you can do 36 million of those per hour.

I know that you want exact answers, but this uses `syevd` and that's should be good enough that you'll only have to double-check values very close to 1.

Comment: Suggest you also subscribe to their users mailing list \\\\\\\\\\\  Date: Fri, Jan 26, 2024 at 9:38 AM  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
Subject: subscribe \\\\\\\\\\\\\
To: <pari-users-request@pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr>     \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\


Not sure how this works. \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

Will Jagy    \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

Answer (score 26):

Are you interested in a clever algorithm, or do you just want to get the answer fast?

If the latter, then I would suggest the following:

1. Use an established off-the-shelf eigenvalue solver.
2. Vectorize your code to work on many matrices at once.
3. Run it on a GPU.

There is an entire universe of experts (in both software and hardware) who dedicate their careers to creating libraries that do dense linear algebra operations extremely fast. Computing the eigenvalues for 100 million 30x30 matrices on the GPU should take less than one second. Computation time will be dominated by the cost of simply moving around the matrices in memory.

Here is some code using the python library jax which generates 1 million random symmetric 0-1 matrices in chunks of 100 thousand at a time, and checks which ones have small eigenvalues:

```
import numpy as np
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from time import time

#### Generate 1 million random matrices in chunks of 100k ####
k = 30
chunk_size = int(1e5)
num_chunks = 10
t = time()
AA = []
for ii in range(num_chunks):
    A_nonsym = np.random.randint(0, 2, (chunk_size, k, k)) # random 0-1 matrices
    A = np.tril(A_nonsym) + np.tril(A_nonsym, -1).swapaxes(1,2) # symmetrize
    AA.append(A)
dt_generate_matrices = time() - t
print('dt_generate_matrices=', dt_generate_matrices)

#### Compute eigenvalues and check if small ####
bad_matrices_all_chunks = []
for ii, A in enumerate(AA):
    # move chunk of 100k matrices from memory to GPU
    t = time()
    A_gpu = jnp.array(A)
    dt_move = time() - t

    # compute eigenvalues
    t = time()
    eigs = jnp.linalg.eigvalsh(A_gpu)
    dt_eig = time() - t

    # Check for small eigenvalues
    t = time()
    bad_matrices = jnp.any(np.abs(eigs) < 1.0, axis=1)
    bad_matrices_all_chunks.append(bad_matrices)
    dt_check = time() - t

    print('chunk: ', ii, ', dt_move=', dt_move, ', dt_eig=', dt_eig)
```

When I run the above code, I get the following timing results:

```
dt_generate_matrices= 13.190782308578491
chunk:  0 , dt_move= 8.313929557800293 , dt_eig= 0.8072905540466309
chunk:  1 , dt_move= 0.2546844482421875 , dt_eig= 0.0008568763732910156
chunk:  2 , dt_move= 0.2372267246246338 , dt_eig= 0.0013964176177978516
chunk:  3 , dt_move= 0.23613929748535156 , dt_eig= 0.0001232624053955078
chunk:  4 , dt_move= 0.23468708992004395 , dt_eig= 0.00011324882507324219
chunk:  5 , dt_move= 0.23540091514587402 , dt_eig= 0.00011682510375976562
chunk:  6 , dt_move= 0.23517847061157227 , dt_eig= 0.00012135505676269531
chunk:  7 , dt_move= 0.23526215553283691 , dt_eig= 0.00012040138244628906
chunk:  8 , dt_move= 0.23635172843933105 , dt_eig= 0.00017189979553222656
chunk:  9 , dt_move= 0.23859858512878418 , dt_eig= 0.00011134147644042969
```

We see that generating 1 million random matrices took 13 seconds. Moving the first batch to the GPU and computing the eigenvalues took 9 seconds, which was almost all compiling time from jax's just-in-time compiler. After that, moving each chunk to the GPU took about 0.25 seconds. The actual eigenvalue computations for each chunk took a miniscule $10^{-4}$ seconds.

Multiplying by 100, the eigenvalue computation time for 100 million 30x30 matrices would be about 0.1 seconds (ignoring the time to generate the matrices, compile the code, and move data to/from the GPU).

Comment: That is incredibly impressive - does this need access to a dedicated computer or can I just use the GPU card on my non-recent desktop. (In general I don’t know how to use GPUs in this way.)

Comment: @GordonRoyle There are lots of tools for doing linear algebra on GPUs, but I like to use jax because it is in python and the syntax mirrors numpy. If you have a supported GPU, you just install jax with GPU support, then replace numpy function calls with jax.numpy function calls where appropriate. Generally Nvidia GPUs are supported, and other GPUs may or may not have experimental support. Mac GPU support is listed as experimental but I have heard it works fine. The list of supported GPUs is here: https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Answer (score 20):

I am not sure if this is going to be faster than what you are doing now (which is already a clever method), but you can try the following.

- Compute $B = A^{-1}$. We know that $A$ has an eigenvalue in $(-1,1)$ iff $B$ has an eigenvalue outside $[-1,1].$
- You can run a few iterations of the power method to compute an approximate leading eigenvector of $B$: i.e., compute the first terms (let's say $m=10$ terms) of the sequence $v_0 = \text{random vector}$, $v_{k+1} = Bv_k$. The absolute value of the Rayleigh quotient $|v_m^* B v_m / v_m^* v_m|$ should converge to the spectral radius of $B$, for $m\to\infty$.
- If the resulting vector after $m$ iterations has a Rayleigh quotient $v_m^* B v_m / v_m^* v_m$ outside $[-1,1],$ then you can conclude for certainty that $B$ has an eigenvalue outside $[-1,1],$ since Rayleigh quotients lie in the convex hull of the eigenvalues of a matrix. This is easy to see by switching to an orthonormal basis in which $B$ is diagonal.

This gives you a quick test that may produce false negatives but not false positives, and thus it can be used to eliminate matrices quickly. Everything can be done in exact rational arithmetic.

Possible tricks for speedup (which might require testing):

- You can repeat the procedure for different random $v_0$ if you wish, but I imagine that it's more effective to increase the number of steps $m$ rather than restart the whole procedure.
- Instead of computing the inverse, you can compute a $LU$ or $LDL^*$ factorization of $A$, and use it to solve linear systems rather than computing inverses. This should be faster, in theory, but Sagemath is Python, so its performance is always tricky to predict.
- I am not expert in the area, but I think there are also LU-like factorization algorithms that can factor out denominators and work entirely in $\mathbb{Z}$. Using them might give further speedup.
- Alternatively, you can run all the steps in floating-point arithmetic, then replace $v_m$ with a nearby rational/integer vector $w_m$. If $w_m$, however computed, has $|w_m^* B w_m / w_m^*w_m| > 1$, then you can prove rigorously that $A$ has an eigenvector inside $(-1,1)$.

My guess is that this procedure is about as fast as computing a determinant (since they both require about $2/3 n^3$ operations asymptotically for an $n\times n$ matrix), but is more effective in weeding out matrices that have a small eigenvalue.

Comment: I would add one other idea before using the power method. Add up the absolute values of all rows and all columns in B. If either the row maximum or the column maximum is <=1, then A will not have small eigenvalues.

Comment: For those looking for more references, this method sometimes goes under the name "inverse power method".

Comment: To implement the inverse power method, it is probably better to solve the sparse linear system $A v = v_k$ rather than to compute $A^{-1}$ explicitly.

Comment: For my matrices, computing the inverse takes about the same time as computing the characteristic polynomial - this may be just because my matrices are sparse (which I did not specify in the original question). The technique though works very nicely and normally finds a large eigenvalue within a couple of iterations. Now I need to experiment with replacing the inverse-finding with solving the system of linear equations (as per @Alf).

Answer (score 13):

A symmetric matrix $A$ has an eigenvalue in $(-1,1)$ iff $A^2$ has an eigenvalue in $[0,1]$. Equivalently this means that
$$
\min_{\Vert v\Vert=1} \frac{\Vert Av\Vert^2}{\Vert v\Vert^2} <1.
$$
Hence you need to decide if the minimum of a nonnegative quadratic function on the unit sphere is $<1$.

I can think of two ways of doing this  but I cannot comment on the computational complexity.

The first is a Monte Carlo type method. Sample $v$ uniformly on the sphere and compute $\Vert A v\Vert$. If the sample is large  and there exists an eigenvalue  of $A^2$ that is $<1$ you can pick detect this with high confidence. Technically, if the size of of the matrix is $n\times n$, then choose the coordinates  $v_1,\dotsc, v_n$  of the random vector $v$ to  be independent  standard normal random variables  and test if
$$
\Vert A v\Vert^2 <\Vert v\Vert^2.
$$

Here's a justifications. One can choose an orthonormal basis  of your ambient space consisting of eigenvectors  $e_1,\dotsc, e_n$ of $A^2$ corresponding to eigenvalues $\lambda_1\leq \cdots \leq \lambda_n$. If $\lambda_1<1$ then $\Vert Av\Vert^2<1$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $e_1$ on the unit sphere $\{\Vert v\Vert=1\}$.  The probability that a random vector  $v$ lands in $U$ is proportional to the size of $U$.
Here's a rough lower bound of  the probability  that $\Vert A\Vert<1$ given that $\Vert v\Vert=1$.  Denote by $\sigma_k$ the area of the $k$-dimensional  unit sphere.

Denote by $\lambda_\min$ respectively $\lambda_\max$ the smallest and respectively the largest of the eigenvalues  of $A^2$. The nontrivial case is $\lambda_\min<1<\lambda_\max$, i.e., $\lambda_1=\lambda_\min$, $\lambda_n=\lambda_\max$.

Denote by $(v_1,\dotsc, v_n)$ the Euclidean coordinates determined by the basis  $e_1,\dotsc, e_n$. Then
$$
\Vert A v\Vert^2=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_kv_k^2.
$$
if $\Vert v\Vert=1$, then $v_1^2=1-\sum_{k=2}^n v_k^2$ and
$$
\Vert A v\Vert^2=\lambda_\min+\sum_{k=2}^n(\lambda_2-\lambda_\min)v_k^2 \leq\lambda_\min +(\lambda_\max-\lambda_\min)\sum_{k=2}v_k^2.
$$
Thus, if $\Vert v\Vert =1$ and
$$
\sum_{k=2}v_k^2<\frac{1-\lambda_\min}{\lambda_\max-\lambda_\min}=:\gamma(A),
$$
then $\Vert Av\Vert<1$.  In other words, if $\Vert v\Vert=1$ and $|v_1|>\sqrt{1-\gamma(A)}$, then $\Vert Av\Vert<1$. $\DeclareMathOperator{\Prob}{Prob}$.  Hence
$$
\Prob\big[ \Vert Av\Vert<1\big|\;\Vert v\Vert=1\big]\geq \frac{1}{\sigma_{n-1}}{\rm area}\;\big(\{v\in S^{n-1};\;v_1^2>1-\gamma(A)\}\big)
$$
$$
=\frac{\sigma_{n-2}}{\sigma_{n-1}}\int_{1-\gamma(A)\leq v_1^2\leq 1}^1 (1-v_1^2)^{(n-3)/2} dv_1=\frac{\sigma_{n-2}}{\sigma_{n-1}}\int_{1-\gamma(A)}^1 (1-s)^{(n-3)/2}s^{-1/2} ds.
$$
(The component $v_1$, as a random variable defined on the unit sphere  has a  Beta  distribution)
$$
\frac{\sigma_{n-2}}{\sigma_{n-1}}\int_{1-\gamma(A)}^1 (1-s)^{(n-3)/2}s^{-1/2} ds=\frac{1}{B((n-1)/2,1/2)}\int_0^{\gamma(A)} s^{(n-3)/2}(1-s)^{-1/2} ds. $$

We have
$$
B((n-1)/2,1/2)\sim \Gamma(1/2)\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}},
$$
and
$$ \int_0^{\gamma(A)} s^{(n-3)/2}(1-s)^{-1/2} ds \approx \frac{2}{n-1}\gamma(A)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}.$$

The expected time to detect $\Vert Av\Vert<1$ is about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\gamma(A)^{-n/2}$

Hence for $n<30$   the sample size ought to be in the millions.  I cannot estimate how long it would take to run such samples. (I've run samples of this size on my laptop.) The computation of $\Vert Av\Vert$ is not very time consuming since $A$ is a $0/1$ matrix.

If one your samples yield a vector such that $\Vert Av\Vert^2<1$  then game over.

If your samples yield only numbers $\Vert Av\Vert^2$ substantially bigger than $1$ then you can say with high confidence that $A$ has no small eigenvalues. If the numbers $\Vert A v\Vert$ are bigger than $1$  "many" are close to $1$ there is a bit of ambiguity.

**Question.**  A natural question comes to mind. Suppose that
$$
A=(A_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}
$$
is a random  symmetric $0/1$ matrix: the coefficients $A_{ij}$, $1\leq i\leq j\leq n$ are independent Bernoulli random variables with probability of success $1/2$. It would be interesting to know the probaility $p(n)$ that $A$ has an eigenvalue in $[-1,1]$

The second approach is  by gradient descent. Consider the   function
$$
f:\{\Vert v\Vert=1\}\to [0,\infty),\;\;f(v)=\Vert Av\Vert^2.
$$
A  flow line  $v(t)$ of the negative gradient flow
$$
\frac{dv}{dt}=-\nabla f(v)
$$
will converge exponentially to an eigenvector of $A^2$.  If the initial condition $v(0)$ is uniformly random on the unit sphere, then, with probability $1$, this flow line will converge exponentially to an eigenvector corresponding to a minimal eigenvalue.

Solve numerically this equation with random initial condition $v(0)$. I speculate that this discretization will  lead you very fast to a decision concerning small e-values.  The speed of convergence depends on how "packed" are the eigenvalues of $A^2$: if they are all packed in a small interval, the convergence will be slower.

Again, I cannot comment on the computational complexity of this approach.

Answer (score 10):

This subtle question requires subtle answers. To begin with, let me discard a few strategies that seem erroneous when the matrices $A\in{\bf Sym}_n$ have a very large size $n$.

- Random sampling: compute $x^TAx$ with $x$ randomly chosen in the the unit sphere. It was shown (in T. Gallay & D. S., *Comm. Pure Appl. Math.* 2012) that this number is, with very high probability, close to $\frac1n{\rm Tr}A$, and thus does not give information about the small eigenvalues.
- Solve the differential equation $\dot x=-Ax$ (assuming that $A$ is positive). Doing so with precision requires the inversion of some matrix $hI_n+A$, which is way too costly.

Is suggest instead the following, based upon the QR method (see my book **Matrices**, 2nd edition, chapter 13.2). In principle, QR is meant to compute the whole spectrum of $A$, which is not needed here, but we only have to implement a small number of iterations (see below). One of the advantages of QR is that the matrix $A$ is transformed by orthogonal conjugations, and thus the numerical errors are not amplified: QR is a very stable method.

First of all, you may assume that $A$ is positive (otherwise replace $A$ by $A^2$). Then put $A$ in tridiagonal form, in about $\frac23n^3$ operations. Every QR iteration will cost only $O(n)$ iterations and the iterates $A^{(k)}$ remain tridiagonal ; this is incredibly cheap ! Then proceed: it is known that the QR sequence converges to ${\rm diag}(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n)$ where $\mu_1\ge\cdots\ge\mu_n(\ge0)$ are the eigenvalues. You are interested in $\mu_n$, aren't you ? Good news: the convergence is the fastest (by far) at the south-east corner. In other words you need very few iterations (say a dozen) to have a very good approximation of $\mu_n$.

Comment: Note that $n$ (the size of each matrix) is not too large (OP says $n < 30$), it is that we must do this many millions of times.

Comment: @KevinCasto $n=30$ is already large enough for these concentration results regarding random sampling to be significant.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if the matrix $$A^T A - I$$ is positive definite. This can be done with Cholesky Decomposition, which runs in time $O(n^3)$ and fails for non-positive-definite matrices.

If $A^TA -I$ is not positive definite, then there is some $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x(A^T A -I )x < 0$, therefore
$$x^T(A^T A)x< \Vert x\Vert^2 \implies \lambda_\min(A^TA)<1\implies \lambda_\min(A)\in(-1,1)$$

---

I came across something surprising: by generating random 0/1 matrices, it seems that all of them contain an eigenvalue $\lambda_\min(A) \le [-1,1]$. Is it just that counter-examples are rare?

Comment: Yes, they exist but are rare.

Answer (score 3):

YES, the pari/gp function called qfsign()   does use rational numbers only!!!!!  You may use it and not fear!

Got a reply from Bill Allombert himself, on a mailing list

[image]

[image]

Pari-gp has a version of what I did, naming it after Gauss rather than Lagrange, in the French manner. It is quick, just field operations, so all are rational numbers if you give it integers.

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9duction_de_Gauss

[image]

because I can then copy and paste each line  and not introduce errors.

Something I have programmed:  see comment of Brendan McKay, but as an if and only if... Sylvester's Law of Inertia says that we may decide this if the counts of negative, positive, zero eigenvalues change a little among three symmetric matrices, call them $H, H+I, H-I.$

The hard part was making it give Latex code as output.  This is all C++  with GMP; note I wrote my own fractions ... Altogether it is three files, about 200 lines each:  myfrac.h  ///      matrixrational.h ///  matrix_congruence.cc

Next given an integer symmetric matrix $H,$   we may solve $P^T  H P = D$  diagonal  for $P$  **nonsingular with rational entries**. Once we have $D$ we just count the diagonal elements, how many positive, how many negative, how many zero.   The same counts doing the same thing for $H-I$  and $H+I$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
2 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
2 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
2 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
2 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

next $H-I$
$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 2 & 0 &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

next $H+I$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 8 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
3 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 8 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 18 }{ 7 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 8 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 21 }{ 8 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 18 }{ 7 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 8 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 8 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 7 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr} 
3 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: The command "qfsign" from Pari/GP computes the signature of the quadratic form associated with the matrix - I have never dared to use it because I do not know if it uses exact arithmetic, and I have been bitten too many times by numerical instability. But your answer here suggests that it is possible to do this in rational arithmetic - do you know if Pari/GP actually does this?

Comment: @GordonRoyle  yes, both qfsign() and qfgaussred()  use exact arithmetic, integer and rational numbers

Answer (score 2):

I am not currently allowed to comment, so I am writing this trivial observation as an answer instead.

A very slight variation of the method you are currently using is possible. The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues and it is easy to see that a product of real numbers can only be in the interval $(-1,1)$ if at least one of the numbers is also in $(-1,1)$. Therefore rather than rejecting matrices with determinant equal to zero you can reject all those with determinant in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: The determinant of a 0/1-matrix is an integer, so this observation only rules out those matrices with determinant 0 (for which it is obvious there is a small eigenvalue, namely 0).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Mea culpa, I missed the restriction that the matrices are integer valued.

Answer (score 2):

The power iteration technique is often used to calculate the dominant eigenvalue/eigenvector of an arbitrary matrix. The power iteration technique is simple and efficient, but it does not always work and it only gives the dominant eigenvalue/eigenvector, but power iteration works better for symmetric matrices. We can use the power iteration (or some other iterative algorithm) to calculate the minimum eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix as well.

Suppose that $A$ is symmetric (the eigenvalues need to be real for this to work). Let $B=A^2$. Suppose that $B$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1\geq\dots\geq\lambda_n$. Let $\mu>0$. Let $C=\mu\cdot I-B$. Then $C$ has eigenvalues $\mu-\lambda_1,\dots,\mu-\lambda_n$. If $|\mu-\lambda_n|\geq|\mu-\lambda_1|$, then the spectral radius of $C$ will be $\mu-\lambda_n$ and this spectral radius may be computed using power iteration. While we want $|\mu-\lambda_n|\geq|\mu-\lambda_1|$, it is better if $\mu$ is not too large since we want the power iteration to converge quickly.

To use the power iteration, we begin with a random vector $v_0$, and then we set $v_{r+1}=Cv_r$ for all $r$. Each step in the power iteration can be computed efficiently since $Cv_r=\mu\cdot v_r-A(Av_r)$ where the parentheses indicate the fastest order of operations (we do not need to compute $B$ to get $Cv_r$). In this case, $\|v_{r+1}\|/\|v_r\|$ will converge to the spectral radius of $C$.

Comment: This is a nice variation of the inverse power method.